# Proving $l^{\infty}$ not separable.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, separable-spaces

I have proved the fact that $l^\infty$is not separable.I just want to verify whether my proof is correct.Suppose $A$ is a countable set in $l^\infty$.We have to show $A$ is not dense.Suppose $A=\{r_1,r_2,....\}$,then we construct a sequence $\xi$ as follows:

$\xi_i=1$ if $|r_{ii}-1|\nless 1/2$ and $\xi_i=0$ if $|r_{ii}-1|<1/2$,then $\xi\in l^\infty$ and $r_n \notin B(\xi,{1\over 2}) ,\forall n\in \mathbb N$.So,$B(\xi,{1\over 2})\cap A=\phi$,so $A$ is not dense.Is the proof alright,or some modifications can be made to make it much easier and shorter?

Comment: The set of binary sequences are non-countable and belong to $l_\infty$. And the distance between any two of its points is 1.

Comment: @thing I know the proof but I just want to verify this proof(what I have done).

Comment: what is $r_{ii}$ ? @KishalaySarkar

Comment: @infinity $r_{ii}$ is the $i$ th term of the sequence $r_i$.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar can you tell me, what's the idea to construct a sequence $\xi$? is it started by our goal, i.e. show that $r_n\notin B(\xi,\frac{1}{2})$ which is $\sup_{i\in \mathbb{N}}|r_{ii}-\xi_i|\geq \frac{1}{2}$? I try to understand your construction of $\xi$, but I don't understand how can we get $|r_{ii}-1|<\frac{1}{2}$ and $|r_{ii}-1|\geq \frac{1}{2}$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is fine, in essence a diagonal argument to show that any countable subset cannot be dense in $\ell^\infty$.